# Why are there differences of the work function of electrons from silver ?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, work

So I have found several values for the work function from silver:

```
4.05 eV and 4.6 eV
```

So why are there differences of the work function of electrons from silver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function#Work_functions_of_elements[11]):

Note that the work function depends on the configurations of atoms at the surface of the material. For example, on polycrystalline silver the work function is 4.26 eV, but on silver crystals it varies for different crystal faces as (100) face: 4.64 eV, (110) face: 4.52 eV, (111) face: 4.74 eV.